# How to respect Single responsibility principle and use exception handling at the same time?

Tags: exceptions, class-design, single-responsibility

I am getting confused on how exactly should I be using exception handling inside a class that respects S-Principle.

For example consider this code in C#:

```cs
public class BcryptDecrypt    
{    
    private string _password;
    private string _hash;

    public BcryptDecrypt(string password, string hash)
    {
      this._password = password;
      this._hash = hash;
    }

    public bool Verify()
    {
        return BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(this._password, this._hash);
    }    
}
```

Clearly it states that it decrypts a bcrypt hash. But you can see in the `Verify` method there is no try-catch block to handle an exception.

If we add a try-catch to handle exception then we cannot follow S-Principle. So how do software engineers solve this issue?

```cs
// After adding try-catch
public class BcryptDecrypt    
{    
    private string _password;
    private string _hash;

    public BcryptDecrypt(string password, string hash)
    {
      this._password = password;
      this._hash = hash;
    }

    public bool Verify()
    {
        try
        {
            return BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(this._toDecrypt, 
                                            this._hash);
        }
        catch (System.Exception SomeException)
        {
            // Handle exception as you like and break S-Principle
        }
    }    
}
```

One way I thought of is to make a separate class to handle each method or class exception or make a universal class to handle it.

I saw similar question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649865/catching-exceptions-while-following-solid-principles-in-winrt), but the only given answer said to re-throw the exception to let the controller handle it. This doesn't sound like a solution to me considering the controller itself would be following the S-Principle.

Comment: In what way are you handling the exception?

Comment: @JacquesB I am not actually sure yet. Sometimes I may need to handle based on exception while other times it could be universal.

Comment: OK, but you can handle exception in a way which doesn't break single-responsibility. It depends on what you actually do. Having a catch does not in itself break the SRP, but the code inside the catch could break it, depending on what the code actually does. In that case the solution is to not handle the exception at that level.

Comment: @JacquesB Then what is your suggestion, what should I do with that exception ? Suppose I am extracting data from database, I got an unknown exception, what would be the possible solution in that case ?

Comment: If you get an unknown exception, then you cannot meaningfully handle it. So the correct is not to catch it. Only catch exception you can meaningfully handle on the current level.

Comment: @JacquesB apart from *perhaps* in `main` where you log "oops I died" before exiting

Comment: @Caleth I was about to ask that :)

Comment: What do you consider the responsibility of your class to be? Currently the whole class seems unnecessary, it's just a meaningless wrapper around `BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify`.

Comment: I wish people never heard about the SRP. It is singlehandedly the most misinterpreted rule of all.

Comment: You could handle the exception, leave a trace (log) and return "false". Wether `BCrypt` failed or not doesn't matter, the pair *password-hash* is invalid. It's a graceful way to end the execution of an execution path that goes nowhere. A reason to do this could be hiding the dependency with `BCrypt` because nothing that comes from it will reach outer layers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Single responsibility ?

There is a fundamental misunderstanding about SRP here:

- **The single responsibility does not mean that a class should do only one thing, but that it should have only one reason to change.**
- In other words, it's not the single responsibility OF the class, but the single responsibility FOR the class to change.  So it's about decision making.
- Here an [enlightening article from Uncle Bob](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html), who invented SOLID, and explains it better than I with all his authority on the subject.

In consequence, you may very well do exception handling in that class without any design concern.  You could even have a single `Cypher` class for encrypting, decrypting and autochecking itself, if you'd really want it.

### Do one thing ?

In Clean Code, Uncle Bob also promotes the **Do-one-thing-and-do-it-well**, for functions. This could be questioned for exception handling:

- *Do one thing* is not the same as do half of the thing
- If something bad happens when you do the thing, and if you would not handle it as you should, then you would not do the thing well.
- So exception handling does not infringe do-one-thing.

Your option 2 is therefore acceptable.

### Anything about try/catch ?

The only remaining principle to consider for your function is **[Single Level of Abstraction Principle](https://markhneedham.com/blog/2009/06/12/coding-single-level-of-abstraction-principle/) ([SLAP](https://dev.to/_arunsasi/slap-your-functions))**:

- if you `try` on some high level function, you should `catch` and do some high level function.
- It would not be sound to have a catch clause that would be very low level and detailed, like two page of code for the catch vs 1 line for the try.

If exception handling gets too complex, here a nice pragmatic [advice](https://alvinalexander.com/programming/clean-code-quotes-robert-c-martin):

> It is better to extract the bodies of the try and catch blocks out
>   into functions of their own.

Comment: The "Reason to change" description is equally if not more confusing and is not a clarification. Uncle Bob clearly did a terrible job of explaining it because there is so much confusion on this subject.

Answer (score 10):

Don't catch exceptions as soon as they are thrown. Catch exceptions at the point you can do something meaningful with them.

But your example code shouldn't be throwing *there*. The only reasonable exception is `ArgumentNullException`, which *you* should throw in the constructor.

```
public class BcryptDecrypt    
{    
    private string _password;
    private string _hash;

    public BcryptDecrypt(string password, string hash)
    {
      Ensure.ArgumentNotNull(password, nameof(password));
      Ensure.ArgumentNotNull(hash, nameof(hash));

      this._password = password;
      this._hash = hash;
    }

    public bool Verify()
    {
        return BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(this._password, this._hash);
    }    
}
```

[`Ensure.ArgumentNotNull` from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184887/best-way-to-check-for-null-parameters-guard-clauses).

Comment: But how would that handle the exception ? If I use if-else block to check and return on null then it would mean I am breaking S-Principle as the class is meant to decrypt hash only.

Comment: @Suleman **It wouldn't**. Somewhere closer to the user would, where you have the context to know what to do.

Comment: I see, so basically we handle the possible exceptions at the point of their possible existence. But then this means I actually remove the try-catch block ? Wouldn't it mean running a code without handling unknown exceptions ?

Comment: @Suleman Yes. By **definition** you shouldn't handle unknown exceptions, because you don't know what to do.

Comment: @Suleman Your method also becomes more reusable if you let the caller decide how to handle exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

You didn’t understand the Single Responsibility Principle.

It means: Do one thing - completely. With everything that is needed to make it work. Like exception handling. Adding another class for exception handling would be utterly ridiculous.

A chef cooking a lobster takes a pot, fills it with water, puts it on the oven, turns the heat on, waits until the water is boiling, throws in the lobster, and so on. SRP does *not* say that you need a PotTakerClass, a PotWithWaterFillerClass, a PotOnOvenPutterClass and another dozen classes.

SRP doesn’t even say you need a LobsterCookerClass. All you need is one ChefClass with the single responsibility to cook food. PS. A good chef is like god, and there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I don't think you understand SRP either. It doesn't say anything like "Do one thing - completely."

Comment: You're describing a god class, and it's considered harmful.

Comment: @JacquesB I'm not reciting any definition. OP has probably seen a definition and completey misinterpreted it.

Comment: I'm not opposed to this way of thinking about it provided you understand that "things" can nest. Your "one thing" should be one abstraction. One simple idea. Not something that can't be broken down into smaller things. That story is different for functions.

Comment: @JacquesB: the catch is the understanding of level of abstraction. The Lobster class example is appropriate for a restaurant. It's not appropriate, and a PotWaterFiller class would make sense, in other situations, such as a huge industrial plant churning out 50 cooked lobsters a second. Not all software targets the same environments.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you may be misunderstanding SRP. Don't feel bad though, SRP is not well defined. You would be better off just to ignore it and concentrate on other more well-defined principles like [Coupling and Cohesion](https://speakerdeck.com/robertbraeutigam/single-responsibility-principle) and the [Law of Demeter](https://dzone.com/articles/the-genius-of-the-law-of-demeter).

I'm not really here to comment about that though, but about your design. You say:

> Clearly it states that it decrypts a bcrypt hash.

It shouldn't state what it *does*, but what it *is*. Objects are things, not procedures. So, what it should be is "BcryptHash". And it probably should verify whether a string hashes into it. Something like:

```cs
public class BrcyptHash {
   private string _hash;
   ...
   public bool IsOf(string text)
      ...
```